# Base-Class only Methods?

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance

**Is there a way of only-base class only methods?**

I have a work around of using a module, but this separates the functionality which will only be utilized by the base-class.

I was think on the line of the following

```
Public MustInherit Class Token
  ' Token stuff
  NotInheritable Shared Function Parse(Of T As Token)(CR As CharReader) As T
    ' Would also be good to be able to do the following without resorting
    ' to the reflection based bodgery.
    Return T.Parser(CR)
  End Function
End Class

Public Class Digit
  Inherit Token
  ' Digit Stuff
  Protected Shared Function Parser(CR As CharReader) As Digit
    If CR.Current.HasValue = False Then Return Nothing
      Case Select CR.Value
        Case "0"c To "9"c
          Return New Digit(CR.Index,0)
      Case Else
        Return False
      End Select
  End Function
```

So now when

```
Dim d0 = Token.Parse(Of Digit)(cr)
```

but

```
Dim d1 = Digit.
```

wouldn't show the Parse Method.

So how can this be done? (If possible at all)

**EDIT**

Current Implementations
This should really a Base Class only method in the Token Class

```
Public Module TokenModule
  Public Function Parse(Of T As Token)(cr As CharReader) As T
  '  
  ' Here Be Nasty Reflection Based Bodge Job 
  '
  ' Why? What I want to write. ( Call a static method on the generic (constrianed) type     specifier.)
  '
  ' Return T.Parser(cr)
  ' 
  ' Start Bodgery {
  Dim tt As T
  tt = GetType(T).InvokeMember("Parser",
                                Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod +
                                Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic +
                                Reflection.BindingFlags.Static, Nothing, tt, {cr})
  Return tt
  ' } End Bodgery
End Function
End Module
```

**Token (Base) Class**

```
Public MustInherit Class Token
  Private _Index As Integer
  Private _Count As Integer
  Protected Friend Sub New(ByVal Index As Integer, Count As Integer)
    _Index = Index : _Count = Count
  End Sub
  Public ReadOnly Property Index As Integer
    Get
      Return _Index
    End Get
  End Property
  Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer
    Get
      Return _Count
    End Get
  End Property
  Protected Shared Function Parser(cr As CharReader) As Token
    Return Nothing
  End Function
End Class
```

**Digit Class**

```
Public Class Digit
  Inherits Token.Token
  Private Sub New(ByVal Index As Integer, Count As Integer)
    MyBase.New(Index, Count)
  End Sub
  Protected Overloads Shared Function Parser(cr As CharReader) As Digit
    Dim crc = cr.Current
    If crc.HasValue = False Then Return Nothing 
      Select Case crc.Value
        Case "0"c To "9"c
          Return New Digit(cr.Index, 1)
        Case Else
          Return Nothing
        End Select
  End Function
End Class
```

Comment: And what would be the use of this?

Comment: What is `CharReader`? I would need to know that to help you with the `Parse` problem.

Comment: It doesn't matter what CharReader does it could be any type.

Comment: @CodyGray I think Partial Inheritance could be useful. Plus being able to call Static/Shared methods on the derived type, from the base-class.

Comment: @CodyGray I suspect it's to prevent nonsensical constructions like `Utf8Encoding.ASCII`

Comment: @Code: I don't see why you would solve a poor name choice with a complex design pattern. @Adam`: "Partial inheritance" is called composition. I don't know what you mean about being able to call static methods on the derived type from the base class. As I understand it, you can, that's what polymorphism is all about.

Comment: I Ask Token.Factory to build me a Digit Token.  
 Token.Factory "places an Order" at the Digit Factory.  
 Digit.Factory return a Digit Token which passed back Token.Factory.  
 The Token.Factor passes back to me the Digit Token.  Can't test for validity in constructors.  So I use factory methods, where check validity before creating a instance.

Answer (score 2):

That kind of relationship really breaks the OO Concepts. If a parent type provides public functionality, then the child should as well (think Child is a Parent).

The kind of functionality you want can easily be achieved via composition (Digit would contain an instance of Token and proxy whatever calls are necessary to that instance) rather than inheritance.

Comment: I require Digit to be subtype of Token, as they can be put into a type -safe container rather than using object.

Comment: @AdamSpeight - Then create an interface that you can apply to both the Token and Digit that exposes only the functionality that you need.

Comment: Parse should be Static/Shared. Since the code that will be contain in the Parse method is common to **all** instanced of the class it should really be shared. So that requirement rules this out It also rules out Interfaces. What I need is a **class object** itself not an instance of that class.

Comment: How can a Parent be a Child? wouldn't that be a bit circular.

Answer (score 1):

> wouldn't show the Parse Method.

Not sure I follow but you only seem concerned about IntelliSense showing the method.  That's easy to solve with EditorBrowsableAttribute:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
...
Class Token
    Public Shared Sub Parse()
        '' etc
    End Sub
End Class

Class Digit
    Inherits Token

    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)> _
    Public Shared Shadows Sub Parse()
        Token.Parse()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Parse should be Static/Shared. Since the code that will be contain in the Parse method is common to **all** instanced of the class it should really be shared. So that requirement rules this out It also rules out Interfaces. What I need is a **class object** itself not an instance of that class.

Comment: So, just make them Shared then.  Post updated, still works.  This is as far as you can push it without redesigning the principles of OOP.

Comment: But you can still write Digit.Parse(). The PARSE should only exist on the **Token** object not any of it descendants object, not invisible from intellisense.

Comment: I thought I was pretty explicit about this.  You can only hide it from IntelliSense, "un-inheriting" a method is just not possible.  It would be quite a pointless feature, the client code can always cast to the base class to get access to the method.

Comment: Then why are Constructors (New) not inherited?

Comment: Click the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 0):

If `CharReader` implements `IConvertible`, you can convert it to other types with `System.Convert`. The standard types like `Boolean`, `String`, `Char`, `Int32`, `Double`, etc. implement `IConvertible`.

```
Shared Function Parse(Of T As Token)(ByVal CR As CharReader) As T
    Return DirectCast(Convert.ChangeType(CR, GetType(T)), T)
End Function
```

--

`Parse` can be hidden by shadowing it with a non public method

```
Protected Shared Shadows Function Parse(ByVal CR As CharReader) As Digit
                    ^
                    |
            (note the Shadows keyword)
```

Note that this works only for shared methods, since you access them through the type name and not through an instance.

Comment: But I want .Parse to only be accessible on the Token class.  Token.Parse(Of Digit) not  Digit.Parse() or any other derived sub- class of Token.

Comment: If you declare `Parse` with the `Shadows` keyword and as protected and you type `Digit.`, intellisense will not show any `Parse` method!